# Regex: match string followed by dot/comma followed by space

Tags: python, regex

i want to turn my `text = "hello this is me, and only me. be carefull from 911. "`

into : `text = "hello this is me,<break></break> and only me.<break></break> be carefull from 911. "`

only for strings followed by dot or comma not number.

i tried with this expression: `r"\w+([.,])+\s*"` but it match also numbers.

Comment: in that case there should be break after "911." as well

Comment: @Neeraj no i want to match only words followed by dot or comma not numbers.

Comment: @00 yes i tried this expression : r"\w+([.,])+\s*" , but it match also numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'([^\W\d_][.,])(\s+)', r'\1<break></break>\2', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/or4S9Y/1).

*Details*:

- `([^\W\d_][.,])` - Group 1 (`\1`): any letter and then a `.` or `,`
- `(\s+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more whitespace chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Tf6lVJ):

```py
import re
text = "hello this is me,<break></break> and only me.<break></break> be carefull from 911. "
print(re.sub(r'([^\W\d_][.,])(\s+)', r'\1<break></break>\2', text))
# => hello this is me,<break></break> and only me.<break></break> be carefull from 911.
```

Comment: it's working thank you :), 3 mins so i can accept it.